# Does Honours results have an expiry date like a Bachelor degree does?

Tags: phd, application, australia

I completed a First class Honours degree in 2000 and I am now considering doing a PhD. In Australia, degrees older than 10 years are no longer considered valid academically and I was wondering if it was the same for Honours? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer valid"?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the college credits of STEM courses may be no longer considered valid after 10 years when you transfer between colleges, but the degree is always valid once you obtain it. Would you please tell us where did you get the idea that the degree is no longer considered valid after 10 years?

Comment: I haven't ***ever*** encountered an Australian university that absolutely refuses to give credit on the basis of degrees previously granted. Instead, after the elapse of a certain amount of time, there is a tendency for universities to ask about your knowledge and to examine more closely what you actually did in your degree. That way, the university can make a more reasonable assessment of whether your prior degree will adequately prepare you for a particular course, or whether you should complete some additional preparatory "catch-up" work .

Comment: Is the essence of your question "can I be admitted to a PhD program in Australia 20+ years after my Honours degree"?

Comment: I suggest you improve your general understanding of the academic world. If degrees that take 4, 6 or 8 years to do expired in 10 years, no one would do them!

Answer (score 4):

> In Australia, degrees older than 10 years are no longer considered valid academically...

This is not true --- unless they are revoked, awarded degrees remain "academically valid" and recognised forever.  I think what you may be referring to here is the fact that universities in Australia (and presumably also elsewhere) typically have a time limit on how long completed courses can remain valid *for the purposes of gaining learning credit/exemptions in a current degree*.  In order to ensure currency of knowledge in a current degree program, universities often impose a time limit for claiming credit/exemption for a course you have previously undertaken.

For example, in the [ANU Policy for recognition of prior learning](https://policies.anu.edu.au/ppl/document/ANUP_6278391), Clause 7 imposes a ten-year (undergraduate) or seven-year (postgraduate) time limit for recognition:

> 7. Time limits on the eligibility of prior learning for credit and exemptions:
>
> > (a) Unless the Associate Dean (Education) has approved different program-specific periods, prior learning must have occurred within ten years (for credit towards undergraduate degrees) or seven years (for credit towards postgraduate degrees) before the first day of the first session that follows acceptance of the offer to the program.
> >
> > (b) All courses in a completed degree are eligible for consideration if the date of completion falls within the time period specified in (a).
> >
> > (c) Other formal or non-formal courses are eligible if the date of completion falls within the time period specified in (a).

Policies of this kind do not mean that an awarded degree is not "academically valid" if it is too old.  They merely mean that if you enrol in a new degree, you might not be able to claim credit/exemptions towards that new degree from courses you did in your old degree.  If you enrol in a PhD program now, and that program requires coursework, you will probably find that you will not be exempted from the coursework based on courses in your (old) honours degree.  Your previous honours degree remains perfectly valid; it just doesn't give you exemptions from courses in your new program.

Answer (score 3):

In Australia an Honours is a postgraduate degree (it is different elsewhere).  An Honours does not expire.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest that whether the answer is yes or no, your actions should be the same. If you want to join a program, apply for it and make your best case for acceptance.

If it has been a while since your previous degree then you may have some hurdles since your current state of knowledge may be harder to judge. That would be especially true in a fast changing field.

If your activities since graduate support your continuing knowledge in your chosen field, find a way to emphasize that in application materials, such as a Statement of Purpose.

But, degrees *per se* don't expire. Lots of people have gaps of various kinds prior to graduate study.